# How to make xampp compatible with filezilla

Tags: xampp, filezilla

I get a error when I start the xampp

```
Port 21 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.exe""!
20:11:38  [filezilla]   FileZilla WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
20:11:38  [filezilla]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
20:11:38  [filezilla]   or reconfigure FileZilla and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
20:11:38  [filezilla]   Problem detected!
20:11:38  [filezilla]   Port 14147 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.exe""!
20:11:38  [filezilla]   FileZilla WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
20:11:38  [filezilla]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
20:11:38  [filezilla]   or reconfigure FileZilla and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are getting the error due to the port which FileZilla uses being used by another program. You will need to change the FileZilla port to another one.

Comment: By mistake i read wrong question :/.Now tried updating it.

Answer (score 0):

You can disallow your server's own IP address in Filezilla IP filter console. So it won't be able to listen to own.